# Job Activity Monitor - Log File Viewer is showing Duration for running jobs

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent, jobs

As you can see in Log file Viewer it has a column Duration which change for a running job. 
I want to include this column in my query (from  where I get jobname etc)
Any idea to make a SIMPLE script? My only reseacrh so far was sys.dm_exec_sessions and Total_elapsed_time BUT how to connect this to my query where I have my jobname etc?

My query so far;

```
SELECT
ja.job_id,
j.name AS job_name,
ja.start_execution_date,      
ISNULL(last_executed_step_id,0)+1 AS current_executed_step_id,
Js.step_name
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja 
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js ON ja.job_id = js.job_id
AND ISNULL(ja.last_executed_step_id,0)+1 = js.step_id
WHERE ja.session_id = (SELECT TOP 1 session_id FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions
ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC) AND start_execution_date is not null
AND stop_execution_date is null;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It *seems* that, if jobhistory `run_duration` is `null` (meaning the job is still running), you could simply *calculate* the current `run_duration` using `DATEDIFF` between jobactivity `start_execution_date` and `sysdatetime()`.

Since the normal Run_Duration from `jobhistory` is an `int` in HHMMSS format, there are some calculations to achieve that.

Something like:

```
SELECT ja.job_id
    ,j.NAME AS job_name
    ,ja.start_execution_date
    ,ja.stop_execution_date
    ,ISNULL(last_executed_step_id, 0) + 1 AS current_executed_step_id
    ,Js.step_name
    ,CASE 
        WHEN jh.run_duration IS NULL
            THEN 
                convert(int,RIGHT('0' + CAST(datediff(second, ja.start_execution_date, sysdatetime()) / 3600 AS VARCHAR),2)  +
                RIGHT('0' + CAST((datediff(second, ja.start_execution_date, sysdatetime()) / 60) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  +
                RIGHT('0' + CAST(datediff(second, ja.start_execution_date, sysdatetime()) % 60 AS VARCHAR),2))
        ELSE jh.run_duration
        END AS run_duration
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity ja
LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory jh ON ja.job_history_id = jh.instance_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js ON ja.job_id = js.job_id
    AND ISNULL(ja.last_executed_step_id, 0) + 1 = js.step_id
WHERE ja.session_id = (
        SELECT TOP 1 session_id
        FROM msdb.dbo.syssessions
        ORDER BY agent_start_date DESC
        )
    AND start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
    AND stop_execution_date IS NULL;
```

Comment: Perfect! But run_duration is in INT and I want to seconds like: ((run_duration / 10000 * 3600 + run_duration % 10000 / 100 * 60 + run_duration % 100)) as RunningSeconds. How to add in the query?

Comment: @Michael - the _calculated_ run_duration is already in `seconds`.  That's what the `DATEDIFF` is doing.  I guess I don't fully understand what you're asking.

Comment: Of course youre right and Iam wrong in both cases :-) To my defense sysjobhistory har run_duration as INT...

Comment: @Michael - After looking at your question again and looking at the format of the run_duration from jobhistory, I've updated my answer.